# How to copy and paste all the html of the clicked element into a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment I am doing this:

```
var $items = $('<div class="grid-item col-xs-12 col-md-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="' + item.link + '"></div>');
$(".grid-item").on("click", function(){
  var $imageSelected = $(this).html();
  alert($imageSelected);
  $('#usp-custom-4').append($imageSelected); 
});
```

But that alert gives me only the img element

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="...
```

And it is not adding the html to the textarea anyway.

**UPDATE**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmnuvb1x/2) working with first answer now using outerHTML yet not pasting into the textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

1. The function [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) will return inner HTML, you need to use `outerHTML` property using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
2. remove `#` from id attribute in HTML
3. use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to set the value of `textarea` element

*code*

```
$(".grid-item").on("click", function() {
    var $imageSelected = $(this).prop('outerHTML');
    $('#usp-custom-4').val(function(_, currentValue) {
        return currentValue + $imageSelected
    });
});
```

```js
$(".grid-item").on("click", function() {
  var $imageSelected = $(this).prop('outerHTML');
  $('#usp-custom-4').val(function(_, currentValue) {
    return currentValue + $imageSelected
  });
});
```

```css
.grid-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-item">
  <span>1</span>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <span>3</span>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <span>4</span>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <span>5</span>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <span>6</span>
</div>
<textarea id="usp-custom-4"></textarea>
```

Comment: ok that resolve me only a part of it, thanks. It does get the correct html indeed but i get lots of alert as per any element (i got 20 elements) and it is not adding it to the textarea

Comment: @rob.m, can you create a fiddle? it seems you posted only portion of problematic code

Comment: see this, no pasting into the text area https://jsfiddle.net/vmnuvb1x/2/

Comment: @rob.m, see https://jsfiddle.net/520da8x2/1/, remove `#` from id it should be `id="usp-custom-4"`